# how to write a music player in linux using ffmpeg

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, audio-player

i have a course project in making a music player in linux with ffmpeg, can anyone give me some instruction about it. Does anyone know of any good resources for learning how to use ffmpeg? Considering I just want to write a simple music player with support for a broad range of formats and codecs, is ffmpeg too heavyweight for a project of this scope? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific question, there are a lot of tutorials on the Internet like http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html and other tutorials.